# Youtube video not working in header now uploaded on a GoDaddy website

Tags: html, youtube, header

I am a beginner at this coding thing and made a personal website/portfolio. Basically, the video header that once worked (works offline aka not uploaded to GitHub), no longer works.

Here it works: http://stephanie-heintzman.bitballoon.com/

Here it doesnt: http://stephanieheintzman.com/

Can anyone please suggest why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have missing js files on page, for example not found: `http://stephanieheintzman.com/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: thanks Mitch! What does this mean? how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to upload these javascripts on server on the right path.